# PCRE does not match

Tags: c++, pcre

I suppose it's something very stupid, however this does not match, and I have no idea why.
I compiles successfully and everything, but it just doesn't match.
I've already used `RE(".*")` but it doesn't work as well.
The system is OS X (installed pcre using `brew`).

```
std::string s;
if (pcrecpp::RE("h.*o").FullMatch("hello", &s))
{
    std::cout << "Successful match " << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that in real life, you can use the `FullMatch` method without the second parameter and print the original string when you doesn't have to extract subpatterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to extract one subpattern (in &s), but have not included any parentheses to capture that subpattern. Try this (untested, note parentheses).

```
std::string s;
if (pcrecpp::RE("(h.*o)").FullMatch("hello", &s))
{
    std::cout << "Successful match " << s << std::endl;
}
```

The documentation at http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrecpp.html has a similar example, stating:

> Example: fails because there aren't enough sub-patterns:
>   !pcrecpp::RE("\w+:\d+").FullMatch("ruby:1234", &s);

Comment: Yep, that's it, I probably would have found it after a while, but before you start investing, you first want to see a working example :-)